# Problema na função de formatação de preço

Tags: javascript

Tenho um valor pré formatado de `6.5`. Se eu colocar nesta função, ele retorna `0,65`. Se eu colocar `19.5` ele retorna `1,95`.

Porque isso acontece?

```
function formataReal(numero)
{
    var tmp = numero + '';
    var neg = false;

    if (tmp - (Math.round(numero)) == 0) {
      tmp = tmp + '00';
    }

    if (tmp.indexOf(".")) {
      tmp = tmp.replace(".", "");
    }

    if (tmp.indexOf("-") == 0) {
      neg = true;
      tmp = tmp.replace("-", "");
    }

    if (tmp.length == 1) tmp = "0" + tmp

    tmp = tmp.replace(/([0-9]{2})$/g, ",$1");

    if (tmp.length > 6)
    tmp = tmp.replace(/([0-9]{3}),([0-9]{2}$)/g, ".$1,$2");

    if (tmp.length > 9)
    tmp = tmp.replace(/([0-9]{3}).([0-9]{3}),([0-9]{2}$)/g, ".$1.$2,$3");

    if (tmp.length = 12)
    tmp = tmp.replace(/([0-9]{3}).([0-9]{3}).([0-9]{3}),([0-9]{2}$)/g, ".$1.$2.$3,$4");

    if (tmp.length > 12)
    tmp = tmp.replace(/([0-9]{3}).([0-9]{3}).([0-9]{3}).([0-9]{3}),([0-9]{2}$)/g, ".$1.$2.$3.$4,$5");

    if (tmp.indexOf(".") == 0) tmp = tmp.replace(".", "");
    if (tmp.indexOf(",") == 0) tmp = tmp.replace(",", "0,");

    return (neg ? '-' + tmp : tmp);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa tua função tá um desastre, com uma linha consegues fazer isso, sugeria que usasses esta, sempre me deu jeito:

```
function formatNumber(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

Ou se preferires esta também funciona lindamente:

```
function formatNumber(x) {
    var parts = x.toString().split(".");
    parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    return parts.join(".");
}
```

Comment: Obrigado. Funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: Funciona, mas como é que funciona ?

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) para converter valores para o formato monetário.

```
const Money = Intl.NumberFormat('BRL', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'BRL',
});
Money.format(19.50); // Saida R$19,50
Money.format(1550); // Saida R$1.550,00
Money.format(0.25); // Saida R$0,25
```

**Não esqueça sempre de verificar a compatibilidade.**

Answer (score 1):

Em JavaScript existe o **método nativo** [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) para trabalhar valores monetários. Este já atende à tua necessidade especifica, fazendo uso de um locale para formatar o valor de saída:

```js
var numero = 123456.789;
var formatado = numero.toLocaleString('pt-BR', {maximumFractionDigits: 2 });

// Debug
document.getElementById("resultado").textContent = formatado;
```

```html
<span id="resultado"></span>
```

Fazendo uso da opção `maximumFractionDigits`, podemos especificar o número de casas decimais pretendidas.

Comment: Melhorei a resposta com exemplo utilizando locale do Brasil. Também simplifiquei o texto para ficar mais "direto ao assunto".

Comment: Sem problemas ficou melhor mesmo.